# Fill the icons in bottomNavigation

Tags: java, android, material-components-android, android-bottomnav, android-bottomnavigationview

I use `bottomNavigation`.

I wanna fill the icon with the color "not the outside of the icon" when selected.
How can I do that?

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTextStyle"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:itemIconSize="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/buttom_navigation_menu">

</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `itemIconTint` attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
   app:itemIconTint="@color/my_selector"
   ..>
```

and define a selector like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.0" android:color="..." android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="..."/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Unfortunately, it did not work as required, I want it to be like icons on Instagram, so when the user selects icon it filling.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom made images as per your requirement. You would need to add 2 images one for the `active` state and for `deactive` state.

Create a selector `home_icon_selector.xml` for your icon

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_active_icon_here" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_active_icon_here" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_active_icon_here" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_deactive_icon_here" />
</selector>
```

Update your menu `buttom_navigation_menu` to use the selector above

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon_selector"
        android:title="@string/tab_title_home"/>
</menu>
```